# How do I match my Bootstrap 4 modal size to be the same as Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I changed to Bootstrap 4 my modals are all smaller and don't fit the content well. I tried using the class modal-lg, but that makes it too large.  Is there any documentation that shows how to get the modal to be the same size it was in Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Bootstrap as `SASS` ?
If you do, you can change the following variables :

```
$modal-xl:                          1140px !default;  //doesn't exist on Bootstrap3
$modal-lg:                          900px !default;
$modal-md:                          600px !default;
$modal-sm:                          300px !default;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried those. I'm not sure why but my modal-md is smaller than the default in Bootstrap 3 and modal-lg is larger.  I added a class that sets max-width to those values and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to **wrap your modal** into an element `<div></div>` for example.
Then, adjust the wrapper to the grid span you want with class `col...`.
Then make the modal fill `width:100%`.
However, `modal-lg` was a good way to try, you should inspire you from that class to create one to fit your special needs.